# Responsive image using css

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

i want to make my site's logo responsive, i work on joomla 3x and my dafault template is gk_magazine. 
i tried this:

```
#gkLogo.cssLogo {
background: #4d90fe url(../images/logo.png) 
no-repeat 0 0;

max-width:100% !important;
max-height:auto;
display: block;
margin: 0;
```

}

but my logo appears to small. I need help! Thanx in advance

Comment: Does your image is big enought?

Comment: The `max-width` and `max-height` trick works on... images... not background images.

Comment: ok, so what can i do? cause this is the css of the template i work on

Answer (score 1):

Use Background-size property.

**Background-size:272px 120px;** /* for original size */

**Background-size:100%;** /* to fill the width of the parent div/element */

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp